# Are there algorithms for solving a sequence of sparse linear systems of the form $(x_iI+B)y_i = b$?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am struggling to solve a sequence of linear systems of the form

$$(x_i I + B )  y_i = b, \quad i = 1,2,\dotsc,$$

where $I$ is identity, $x_i$ is a real number and $B$ is sparse. Both the matrix $B$ and the right-hand side $b$ are independent of $x_i$. Both $B$ and $b$ are complex.

Iterative methods are inapplicable here because

$$||B^{-1}|| \,\,\,\, \text{sup}_i \,\,\, |x_{i+1} - x_i| \gg 1. $$

Can I exploit the fact that all matrices have the same sparsity pattern?

Comment: A number of iterative methods are applicable to your problem. You should explain which methods are excluded by your condition.

Comment: I have formated your question and made some small changes. Please check carefully that nothing has been lost. You can roll back the changes.

Comment: Can’t you solve it as $B y_i = b - x_i$ with a direct solver? Then you’ll factor the matrix only once and then solve the problem with multiple righthand sides?

Comment: O, sorry, I misread the equation

Comment: Why do you think a Jacobi preconditioner won't work? It looks like  the diagonal is much larger than the spectrum of $B$?